# Run executable on background detached from terminal but with arguments

Tags: terminal, background-process, arguments

I can run an executable in the background and detach it from the terminal with these commands:

```
$ nohup ./executable &
```

or

```
$ ./executable &   
$ disown
```

But none work if I send arguments to the executable:

```
$ nohup ./executable argument &
```

or

```
$ ./executable argument &
$ disown
```

I have tried combining it with the .sh strings and pipes syntax but it does not work either:

```
$ nohup ./executable <<<$'argument' &
```

or

```
$ ./executable <<<$'argument' &
$ disown
```

or

```
$ nohup echo -e "argument" | ./executable &
```

or

```
$ echo -e "argument" | ./executable &
$ disown
```

EDIT: The "./executable" program accepts any number of parameters, like "./executable arg1 arg2" etc... I think the problem is that "&" gets absorbed by "./executable" as a parameter. Also, it is written in Go if that is of any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? This works on Ubuntu 16 using Bash: `nohup sleep 1234 &`, as well as `nohup sleep 1234 &` followed by `disown`.

Comment: What you have *not* shown (or even claimed) is that the executable works with the required arguments in the foreground. Your attempted work-arounds show that you don't understand the difference between command-line args and stdin data.

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere. The arguments/parameters are indeed being passed to the program even when put in the background. That is clear because `./executable` is itself an argument to `nohup`, and that part is working fine! The problem is in `./executable`: Does it accept parameters on the command line? Are you giving it the correct ones?

Comment: @berndbausch The problem is that when I run the program with arguments followed by "&", the program seems to take "&" as an argument to, so if for instance I run "./executable argument &", the program will run and start logging on the console and I will have to stop it with "ctrl" + "c" in order to run "disown" and it will completely stop running at all.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Yes the program runs normally with arguments, it is designed like that. So if I run "./executable argument" it will work, and start logging on the console and block input  unless I press "ctrl" + "c" and stop the program. And yes I am a bit of a newbie in linux and dont really understand the difference between stdin and args, I will look into it.

Comment: @C.M Yes ./executable accepts parameters in the command line, I wrote it myself, and "./executable argument" runs as expected, logging in the console and blocking input until I press "ctrl + c" to stop it

Comment: So you mean it's a specific executable that displays this behaviour, not just any. I think the program is unable to handle being in the background, without standard input, but without knowing the code, nothing can be said. What makes you think that `&` is passed as an argument? Why are you surprised that it starts writing to the terminal? What **does** it write? Also, I doubt ctl-c has an effect on a background process.

Comment: @berndbausch You are right, I will write a sample program and post it here

Comment: Test it yourself. Create a simple program (c/c++, perl, python. bash shell script, tcl, ...  whichever you prefer) that when it is executed, it simply opens a log file (name it something like "mytest.log") and writes to the log file the command lines arguments it was given. Then be sure to flush and close the log file (else nothing might be written!), and exit the program. Then try using that: `nohup ./mytestprogram &`, and then look in the log file. Then try `nohup ./mytestprogram arg1 arg2 &`, and then look at the log file. In either case, the log file should never contain 'nohup' or '&'.

Comment: @berndausch I tested it again today with a simple test program and it turns out both "$ nohup ./executable &"  and "$ ./executable &  $ disown" both work. Then tested again with my program and it works too. I think yesterday I got confused because I was running the program in an AWS instance and after running "top" today I had to scroll down a lot to see the program runing. As a side note "$ nohup ./executable &" is better if your program starts logging immediately non-stop, as running "$ ./executable &"  and then "$ disown" while the program is logging seems a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

After more testing it turns out both `$ nohup ./executable &` and `$ ./executable & $ disown` work for this purposes. I just ahd to scroll down a lot after running `top` to see the program running.

As a side note `$ nohup ./executable &` is better if your program starts logging immediately non-stop, as running `$ ./executable &` and then `$ disown` while the program is logging seems a bit weird.